# What is the simplest way to show that $\cos(r \pi)$ is irrational if $r$ is rational and $r \in (0,1/2)\setminus\{1/3\}$?

Tags: calculus

What is the simplest way to show that $\cos(r \pi)$ is irrational if $r$ is rational and $\displaystyle r \in \left(0,\frac{1}{2} \right)\setminus \left\{\frac{1}{3} \right\}$?

I proved it using the following sequence $x_1 = \cos(r \pi)$; $x_{k} = 2 x_{k-1}^2-1$ and periodicity of the cosine function.
Is there any proof that is based on definition of rational numbers and trigonometric identities only?
Thanks!

Comment: $2 \cos (r \pi) = e^{r i \pi} + e^{-r i \pi}$ is an algebraic integer, so it is rational if and only if it's an integer.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Let us try to rescue another poor question from Unanswered Questions' inferno, following the comment by Qiaochu:

For $\,\,\displaystyle{r=\frac{m}{n} \in\mathbb Q}\,\,\,$ we get that
$\,\,\,2\cos r\pi:=e^{ri\pi}+e^{-ri\pi}\,\,$ , and since  $\,\,1=e^{2mi\pi}=\left(e^{ri\pi}\right)^{2n}\,\,$ we

have 
that $\,2\cos r\pi\,$ is an algebraic integer (as it satisfies an integer monic polynomial), so if it were

also rational it'd have to be an integer (which is not if $\,\displaystyle{r\notin \mathbb Z\,,\,\frac{1}{2}\mathbb Z}\,$), so it must be irrational.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Generic Human.